# selectkey returned no data on mybatis

Tags: plsql, mybatis

i'm trying to call stored procedure on mybatis.
this is my code.

```
<insert id="insertWbs" parameterType="HashMap" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="wbs_unique">
    <selectKey keyProperty="wbs_unique" resultType="string" order="BEFORE" statementType="CALLABLE">
        <!-- <![CDATA[ SELECT #{proj_no}||WBS_${PROJ_NO}_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL ]]> -->
        <![CDATA[ CALL WBS_UNIQUE(#{proj_no, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{X, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR}) ]]>
    </selectKey>
    insert into wbs(proj_no, task_name, wbs_worker, wbs_tester, wbs_ex_start, wbs_ex_end, wbs_unique, task_status)
        select #{proj_no}, #{task_name}, #{wbs_worker}, #{wbs_tester}, to_date(#{wbs_ex_start}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date(#{wbs_ex_end}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), #{wbs_unique}, #{task_status} from dual where not exists
        (select wbs_unique from wbs where wbs_unique = #{wbs_unique})
</insert>
```

the first comment is what i tried to set dynamic sequence but it didn't worked.
this is the error

```
ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

so i decided to use stored procedure to set dynamic parameter which contains 'wbs_', '_seq'.

```
  create or replace PROCEDURE WBS_UNIQUE 
(
  PROJ_NO IN VARCHAR2
 ,X       OUT VARCHAR2
) AS 
  V_QUERY VARCHAR(1000);
BEGIN
  V_QUERY := V_QUERY||'SELECT WBS_'||PROJ_NO||'_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_QUERY into x;
END WBS_UNIQUE;
```

and it works fine on oracle 11g not mybatis... 
the first code i attached throw this error

```
org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: SelectKey returned no data.
```

i can't understand why it's not working on mybatis. did i do something wrong? probably i did but i don't know what i did wrong.
if anyone knows why this happens, please tell me.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first example looks good to me. This how I would do it myself:

```
<selectKey keyProperty="myId" resultType="java.lang.Integer" order="BEFORE">
  SELECT ${proj_no}||WBS_${PROJ_NO}_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
</selectKey>
```

Do not use `#{proj_no}` but `${proj_no}`. The former is for JDBC parameters; the latter (the one you need) is for SQL injection.

Alternatively, the problem could be the value of the property `PROJ_NO` (or is it `proj_no`?) leads to an invalid sequence name:

- Can you check the value of this property?
- Does that sequence actually exist? The error message says it doesn't.

By the way, shouldn't it look more "java-like", something like `projNo`?